# how to get dictionary value as same using python?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, utf, python-unicode

Solved with your help

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
message = {'message1':'நாம்','message2':'செய்தி'}
a={}
for i in message.keys():
  if "message" in  i:
   a[i]=message[i]

status="success"
print a
```

got output:
{'message2':'செய்தி','message1':'நாம்'}

Thanks for all your help!!!!

Comment: Wow!!! Tamil in Python...

Comment: Python 2 *or* Python 3? The difference is important.

Comment: i am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode with 'utf-8' format in order to print/read as it is

```
print message['message1'].decode('utf-8')
```

This will print correctly.

Comment: i know this method can do. But i need to get complete dict  value .  better u should see what i asked as output , i want to get the output to be {'message2':'செய்தி','message1':'நாம்'}

Comment: How you solved it? Can you add it as an answer here as none of our answers helped you in your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing them as literal string:

message = {'message1': r'நாம்','message2':r'செய்தி'}